# What is the difference/ advantage of doing double assignment?

Tags: java, variables

Is there any advantage / is it a bad practice in Java to do the below

```
x = x = 5
```

I saw it in one of my peers code and I was surprised why he would do double assignment?

Is this something that is same as `x = 5` or if `x = x= 5` makes a difference?

Comment: Did you actually see `x = x = 5`, or was it more like `x = y = 5`? The second one makes sense, but the first one is just weird.

Comment: @Tacroy I see x= x= and it made no sense to me why someone would want to do variable assignment as above. I was not too sure if that made any difference/advantage

Comment: *I was surprised why he would do double assignment?* So... what did he say when you asked him about it?

Comment: I did not want to question his coding practice except that I wanted to know for my own good.

Comment: Wouldn't call it a bad practice, it has more of an **insanity** vibe to it. Consider moving your desk farther from his.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a cut & paste error?  There's an apparently not-so-famous (since I can't find a link) quote that says "when you see someone you respect deep in thought, chances are he's thinking about lunch".  You should ask him about it.

Comment: @rao: How you word the question can create a different tone. "Why did you write that? It doesn't make sense." would put the programmer on the defensive. However, asking for clarification about what the line does opens the door more gently. If the description does not make sense, then you should come out an discuss how each of you have different understands of what is being done and what should be done. Your job is to make the code better, programmers should not be offended when an actual bug is found in their code.

Comment: This one is simply a nonsense, period.

Answer (score 11):

> Is there any advantage/ is it a bad practice to do the below
>
> `x= x = 5`

You haven't specified the language, but in most C-like languages the value of an assignment is the value being assigned. That is, the value of the expression `x = 5` is `5`, and the expression you're asking about is essentially the same as doing:

```
x = 5;
x = 5;
```

There's no value in the extra assignment, so no reason to do it.

Now, what you do sometimes see is the assignment of two (or more) variables to some value at the same time, like this:

```
x = y = 5;
```

In this case, you're assigning 5 to `y`, and then assigning the value of that expression (again, 5) to `x`. This ensures that both `x` and `y` get the same value.

Another possibility is that one of the assignments was intended to be a comparison, with the result assigned to the variable being compared:

```
x = x == 5;
```

This isn't a double assignment, it's assignment of the boolean expression `x == 5` to `x`. That is, if the value of `x` is 5 before the expression, `x` will get the value of `true` (some non-zero integer); if `x` is not 5, `x` will be set to `false` (i.e. 0).

Comment: The language I am referring is Java, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: `x = x == 5` works in C, but (thankfully!) not in Java :)

Comment: @AndresF. Agree, and since we now know that the OP is talking about Java, the last part of my answer really doesn't apply.